# Installing sqlserver2008 SP1, the 'select features' is empty?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

when installing sqlserver 2008 sp1 on windows7, when it gets to the 'select features' part the list is empty.

I can't go past that step as I can't select anything and then the validation fails.

Man installing sqlserver2008 on windows7 is a real nightmare!

I have .net 3.5 SP1, trying to install sqlserver 2008 SP1 and its just not going anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Stupid question (maybe), but have you installed SQL Server already?  SP1 doesn't contain the core product.  You need to install SQL Server 2008 RTM, then install SP1.

Comment: no i haven't, I thought this was a full install that was sqlserver w/SP1.